# IIOException when executing jar file

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to export this application to a jar File but once i export my application as a runnable jar file and start it using the console it gives an error (it didn't do that when i started it from eclipse

these are the Files in my Project:

[image]

and this is the stacktrace of the console:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
        at john.z.moohrhuhn.MoohuhnGUI.initialize(MoohuhnGUI.java:57)
        at john.z.moohrhuhn.MoohuhnGUI.<init>(MoohuhnGUI.java:40)
        at john.z.moohrhuhn.Main.main(Main.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.CustomCursor.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.windows.WCustomCursor.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.createCustomCursor(Unknown Source)
        at john.z.moohrhuhn.MoohuhnGUI.initialize(MoohuhnGUI.java:63)
        at john.z.moohrhuhn.MoohuhnGUI.<init>(MoohuhnGUI.java:40)
        at john.z.moohrhuhn.Main.main(Main.java:31)
        ... 5 more
```

and this is the Code in MoohuhnGUI (starting from line 48) :

```
System.out.println("Path: " + getClass().getResource("Cursor.png").toString());
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(getClass().getResource("Cursor.png").getFile());
            img = ImageIO.read(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("problem");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Dimension bestsize = toolkit.getBestCursorSize(300, 300);
        Cursor c = toolkit.createCustomCursor(
                img,
                new Point((int) bestsize.getHeight() / 2, (int) bestsize
                        .getHeight() / 2), "testimg");
        frame.setCursor(c);
        moorhuhn = MoorhuhnFrame.getinstance();
        moorhuhn.init();

        frame.add(moorhuhn);
```

i would be very happy i you guys could help me ;D

Answer (score 1):

```
getClass().getResource("Cursor.png")
```

expects Cursor.png to be in the classpath. when you export the project as a jar, make sure you copy the file Cursor.png to the classpath. And in the manifest.mf file, add the classpath reference:

```
Class-Path: resources
```

So, your target structure could be (for example):

```
moohuhn
 |
 +--moohuhn.jar
 |
 +--resources
     |
     +--Cursor.png
```

And manifest.mf would me:

```
Main-Class: john.z.MoohuhnGUI
Class-Path: resources
```

Remember, manifest.mf should always have a trailing blank line (last line should be blank).

Comment: When i unzip the jarfile cursor.png is inside the same folder as my .class files. Doesnt this mean that it is already added to the classpath? And exactly the same code is working in eclipse...